# AutoCAD VBA - Creating Blocks with a Hatch

Tags: vba, excel, autocad

I am trying to make blocks in AutoCAD that have a circle, number, and solid hatch but I can't seem to get the hatch to work? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong - any help would be great!

```
    ' Create the block
    insertionPnt(0) = Sheet1.Cells(n, 3)
    insertionPnt(1) = Sheet1.Cells(n, 4)
    insertionPnt(2) = 0
    Set blockObj = ACAD.ActiveDocument.Blocks.Add(insertionPnt, namestr)


    'Add the circle to the block
    center(0) = Sheet1.Cells(n, 3)
    center(1) = Sheet1.Cells(n, 4)
    center(2) = 0
    Set circleObj = blockObj.AddCircle(center, Rad(0) / 2)

    'Add hatch to the block
    hatchObj = blockObj.AddHatch(0, "Solid", True)
    hatchObj.AppendOuterLoop (circleObj)
    hatchObj.Evaluate

    'Add text to the block
    Set blocktext = blockObj.AddText(Nums(0), Coords, 0.5)
    blocktext.Alignment = acAlignmentMiddleCenter
    blocktext.TextAlignmentPoint = Coords

    'Insert the block
    insertionPnt(0) = Sheet1.Cells(n, 3)
    insertionPnt(1) = Sheet1.Cells(n, 4)
    Set blockRefObj = ACAD.ActiveDocument.ModelSpace.InsertBlock(insertionPnt, namestr, 1#, 1#, 1#, 0)
```

Comment: `Rad(0) / 2` is this really a circle with radius = 0?

Comment: The code seems to be OK, so what is the result You get? only circle without hatch? Any error message?

Comment: I get a circle without a hatch but no error messages

Comment: Rad(0) is an array that I actually appended all my diameters to so the code loops through and each value in the Rad array and divides it by 2 to get the radius instead of the diameter

Comment: So try to draw the same on modelspace instead of block. Then by select all check (in properties window, if You have 2 or 3 entities selected)
Maybe there is the hatch, but invisible. I'm not sure but as I remember in some shademode hatch with pattern "SOLID" is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

there are two faults

1) a `Set` keyword is missing in `hatchObj = blockObj.AddHatch(0, "Solid", True)`

2) the `AppendOuterLoop` method requires and *array of objects* for the `loop` parameter

so the hatch section should be like:

```
Dim outerLoop(0 To 0) As AcadEntity ' declare the array of objects
Set outerLoop(0) = blockObj.AddCircle(Center, 10#) ' fill it with a circle object
'Add hatch to the block
Set hatchObj = blockObj.AddHatch(0, "Solid", True) '
hatchObj.AppendOuterLoop (outerLoop) 'append the outerloop
hatchObj.Evaluate
```